# EFCore adding temporary ID by AddAsync()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EFCore 5.0.0.

When I `AddAsync (person);` I should be getting a temporary `ID`, and I use this ID to add the `PersonId` for `School` (shown in code below). FInally, I will `SaveChangesAsync()` where everything will be saved. However, the `PersonId` is set to 0. I want to get the temporary `ID` stored instead. How can I do this.

```
await _dbContext.AddAsync(person);

School school = mySchool;
school.PersonId = person.Id;
await _dbContext.AddAsync(school);

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Note: There are many [SO post that talks about the temporary ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732585/ef-core-add-function-returns-negative-id/41737480), but none is related to this post.

Comment: Does your Model configuration is correct according to this article? https://thesharperdev.com/ef-cores-addasync-v-add-method/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen linking entities in EF Core using the temporary id.

Typically what you would do is assign the entity and let EF sort out the ids and relationships.

i.e. in this instance, the `School` will be linked to the `Person`.

```
await _dbContext.AddAsync(person);

School school = mySchool;
school.Person = person;
await _dbContext.AddAsync(school);

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: will the PersonId column get filled with the correct Id when it gets saved ?

Comment: @Illep Yes, it should

Answer (score 12):

Currently accepted answer is valid, but technically incorrect. Assigning navigation property is valid approach, but not mandatory. It's even perfectly valid to not have navigation property at all. As well as explicit FK property. But there is always at least shadow FK property which can be used to setup/maintain the relationship.

So the temporary key concept is part of the EF Core from the very beginning. However EF Core 3.0 introduced a breaking change - [Temporary key values are no longer set onto entity instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#tkv). The link contains an explanation of the old and new behaviors, the reason and possible solutions:

> Applications that assign primary key values onto foreign keys to form associations between entities may depend on the old behavior if the primary keys are store-generated and belong to entities in the `Added` state. This can be avoided by:
>
> - Not using store-generated keys.
> - Setting navigation properties to form relationships instead of setting foreign key values.
> - Obtain the actual temporary key values from the entity's tracking information. For example, `context.Entry(blog).Property(e => e.Id).CurrentValue` will return the temporary value even though `blog.Id` itself hasn't been set.

Bullet #1 makes no sense, Bullet #2 is what is suggested in the other answer. Bullet #3 is the direct answer/solution to your question.

And applying it to your example requires just changing

```
school.PersonId = person.Id;
```

to

```
school.PersonId = _dbContext.Entry(person).Property(e => e.Id).CurrentValue;
```

Of course when you have navigation property and the related entity instance, it's better to use it and let EF Core do its magic. The temporary key is really useful when you don't have navigation property, or you don't have related entity instance and know the key, but don't want to do roundtrip to load it from database (and using fake stub entity instance can lead to unexpected side effects/behaviors). It works well with both explicit and shadow FK properties.

Comment: Hi there, I just tried to submit an edit for a minor typo in your example code, but SO does not allow edits under 6 characters.  I do not feel comfortable altering the rest of your answer to accommodate that weird limit, so I am reaching out to you here instead.  You accidentally wrote "_contexy" instead of "_context" in your second code block.  If that was intentional, please disregard.  Otherwise, now you know.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, of course it wasn't intentional, thanks for pointing out. Cheers.